# Как найти все совпадения в строке

Tags: python

У меня в строке есть несколько слов допустим "яблоко", как мне найти все совпадение и выдать их.
Я пробовал использовать метод find()

Comment: А что вы уже попробовали?

Comment: В том и дело что я не знаю как, find() возвращает первое вхождение. А мне нужны все

Comment: Не существует встроенного метода, который вернет список совпадений, но вы можете написать его самостоятельно. Учитывая, что вы хотите находить совпадения именно слов, вы можете еще разбить строку на список слов и искать совпадения в данном списке. Если вам нужно только количество этих слов, используйте метод count().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

можете использовать `findall` модуля `re`

```
import re
a = 'яблоко, яблоко, апельсин, манго'
print(re.findall('яблоко', a))
```